# Money seized at the border

Tags: schengen, uk-citizens

Plz excuse  my english .... my husband take 30000 pound with him without declaration  and they taking money now and take him to the court its his money but he cant prouve like 100% cause he just sell a house in sirilanka but also the house was in his sister's  name    he trying now to prove it much as he can .... my question  is if he cant prouve it wht is going to happen to him plz answer me soon as possible

Comment: Just to confirm, where is this taking place? And is your husband a UK citizen?

Comment: He have a solicitor  but wht if he cant prouve it is he will go to prison

Comment: Money laundering regulations require any amount over £10,000 be declared when crossing the border. Your husband took £30000 across the border without declaring it. and got caught. Every other aspect of this is now to do with the law, and not travel. He needs a lawyer, and the rest we can't answer.

Comment: @Patricia If, as the OP says, this man has been taken to court I'd say it is very unwise to discuss events in a public space.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass Good point. I've deleted that comment.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass the UK is still in the EU.  There is no law requiring the declaration of cash being taken from the UK to another EU country.  *If* the UK leaves without a deal then *after* that point the first sentence of your comment will be correct, but at the moment declarations are required if the amount is above €10,000 (not £10,000) and the destination is outside the EU.  So it seems that something else must be going on here.

Comment: @phoog Fair enough, although the page linked in Moo's answer below suggests that a declaration may be required on entry to other EU states. In any case, If the OP's husband has been arrested then I don't think it's wise for us to be discussing the specifics of his case here.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I agree the husband’s citizenship may not matter, however tags are sometimes incorrect. As far as I can see, nowhere in the question does it state that this is taking place at the UK border. The UK isn’t the only country that uses the Pound as currency.

Comment: If the seizure took place at UK Exit Immigration, a UK solicitor is needed. If the seizure took place at Entry Immigration for the Schengen area, then an attorney is needed who is licensed to practice in the country of that Schengen Entry Immigration post.

Comment: For anyone thinking of moving significant amounts of money in cash: Get the money converted from cash to bank credit as close to the original transaction as possible. It will be easier to prove ownership and a legitimate source for the money there. Once that is established, moving money by wire transfer is easy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about traveling within the scope defined in the [help].

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. As I understand the OP, the money was transported from Sri Lanka to the Netherlands (that is, into the EU).
2. £30,000 would be above the €10,000 limit which requires a **declaration** when it is transported into the EU. Failure to do so can lead to the detention or confiscation of the money and to other penalties.

Find a lawyer in the Netherlands.

Comment: See also https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/147745/95267

Comment: The currency is given as "pound". The possibly relevant currencies are the Euro, the Sri Lanka rupee, or the British pound.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, good point.